# How do I ignore certain data points when using convolutional LSTM's?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, satellite-image

I am looking to predict ocean current vorticity using kinetic energy and sea surface temperature. My data consists of satellite kinetic energy readings and surface temperature readings in the gulf stream region. I plan to use a hybrid neural network which combines a recurrent architecture (LSTM) with a convolutional network model.

My dataset consists of daily kinetic energy and temperature readings from 1996 to 2018, for a total of 8036x80x120 grids. For example, given the [kinetic energy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOhlS.jpg), and [temperature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVTdo.png), I want the NN to predict the [vorticity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9snd.jpg).

My question is, how can I influence my neural network to ignore/discount land terrain and only focus on the ocean data. The land terrain data is stored in my image arrays as NaN values.

I am using PyTorch.

Answer (score 0):

[All you need is attention](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) will the solution you are looking for. The mechanism will help you to focus on certain features/blocks in your inputs. There is a [medium post](https://medium.com/@moshnoi2000/all-you-need-is-attention-computer-vision-edition-dbe7538330a4) that gives a tutorial of how to apply this mechanism to images.